# PayPal Website Payments Standard Error

Tags: magento, paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I currently have my online store set up using Magento and i’m adding my products, I’ve tried to implement the PayPal Website Payments Standard but there is an error. When the user has passed through to the checkout section, after entering all their details, they fail to submit the order. The button is pressed to confirm order and redirect to the PayPal payment stage, the button will load saying that it's submitting the information, but nothing happens, it starts processing, then never goes through to the page. I've checked that the extension for Mage_paypal is enabled and it is.

If you would like try purchasing one of the test products on www.scarletkisses.com at the moment, you’ll be able to see what I mean.

Thanks.

Comment: hi please enable console & then check

Comment: Enable console? What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Have you configured your paypal credentials correctly? Console has no output.

Comment: There are no products on the site to try this out with. But you can see the response to ajax requests and any javascript errors with the console and network tabs in Google Chrome developer tools, this may shed some light on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things ..

1. Make sure that you have index management and cache management done
2. Try disabling and then enabling Mage_PayPal Module[Reindex the magento database after that]